# SQL query to return any 100 rows quickly without scanning entire table

Tags: sql-server

I want to fire a SQL query that returns any 100 rows from the database table. I understand that using TOP (`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM TABLENAME`) makes the engine scan the entire table and then return results which might take quite some time for a huge table.

Is there a SQL query to return any n rows without making engine to scan the entire table and/or to produce results quickly?

Comment: Trick question: If every record in the table is not fair game for being selected, then how can it be truly random?

Comment: your understanding that TOP without an ORDER BY will scan the entire table is not correct. But the rows selected will not be guaranteed and not random either

Comment: The only way to stop it scanning is to give it some direction on what to find. Which basically means that the table needs a primary key (with an associated index) and you need to specify (randomly) which ones to retrieve

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that isnt correct. the `top 100` is driven by the top operator in the plan, this would stop requesting rows from the scan after it gets 100 for either an unordered scan or ordered index scan

Comment: Generate a random number from 1 to max(ID column) and repeat until you have 100. But I am pretty sure it will be slower then using top

Comment: Do you want "any 100 rows" (it does not matter which) or a random selection of 100 rows. Your question asks for both and they are not the same thing

Comment: Any 100 rows, updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the requirement to get any arbitrary 100 rows from the table the query you have is fine.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM   TABLENAME
```

The execution plan will look something like the below (though might show an index scan rather than a table scan)

[image]

Execution plans in SQL Server operate in a pipelined fashion where operators request rows a row at a time from their child operators (or a batch at a time in batch mode).

Once the `TOP` operator counts that it has received 100 rows from the scan it will stop requesting any more and signal the scan operator that it can close.

The rows returned will not be random. Successive runs of the query may well return the exact same 100 rows. They will not be guaranteed either. They will just be the first 100 returned by whatever access method is used by the subtree under the `TOP`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 999
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 999 ---- The highest random number
SET @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)


SELECT  *
FROM     TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY CHOSEN_COLUMN
OFFSET  @RANDOM ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

This will essentially do what you ask and a good time. What it does is your declaring a upper and lower bound number for the `RAND()` function to choose a number from. Then we use the `ROUND()` function with it as `Rand()` returns a float number.

Simply set whatever you want your `@upper`(highest number) to be, in my case 999. then it selects all columns from your table, `OFFSETS` so basically skips the random X amount of Rows, and gets the next 1 row after that. You can change the numbers such as the fetch part to and say `FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY` if you wish to return the next 100.

Or if you wish to return a random number each time 100 times (so random 100 rows) then we could use a while loop with a counter so be like this:

```
DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT
DECLARE @Cnt INT;

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 999
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 999 ---- The highest random number
SET @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SET @CNT = 0 

WHILE @cnt <= 20

BEGIN
SELECT  *
FROM     TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY CHOSEN_COLUMN
OFFSET  @RANDOM ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY 
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1

END
```

In my case i set the cnt to 20 so this will reuturn a random 20 records etc.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The question was edited 40 minutes ago to remove any mention of random. So this is an answer to a question not being asked

Comment: @MartinSmith well technically it does. My solution does return ANY  X amount of rows such as in OP's question can set the cnt vairable to 100. My solution will therefore return 100 rows from the table. Which if I'm not mistaken is what realistically what OP asked for. So yes the random number is in mine but it still essentially does what OP wants. Return X rows from table.
"Is there a SQL query to return any n rows"
Don't get me wrong your answer is obviously now more accurate and better but my answer can still be accepted in terms of the question.

Comment: unnecessarily complex and inefficient compared with a simple `TOP 100` for the "Any" requirement